# Regex to find anchor tags that link to an image

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, fancybox

I'm using this code in my WordPress theme functions.php to add a "fancybox" class to linked images. However, I *do not* want to add the fancybox class to images that are linked to non-image URLs.

In other words: currently the script will add the "fancybox" class to an HTML structure like this (which I do not want):

`<a href="http://acme.com/a-non-image-link">
     <img src="http://acme.com/image.jpg" />
</a>`

Where as I only want to add the class to structures like:

`<a href="http://acme.com/an-image.jpg">
     <img src="http://acme.com/an-image.jpg" />
</a>`

or

`<a href="http://acme.com/an-image.jpg">
     <img src="http://acme.com/another-image.jpg" />
</a>`

How can I modify the regex expression in this code to only include anchor tags whose HREF attribute contains `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, or `.gif`?

Thank you!

```
        // Add fancybox class to linked images
        function add_classes_to_linked_images($html) {
            $classes = 'fancybox fancybox-img'; // can do multiple classes, separate with space

            $patterns = array();
            $replacements = array();

            $patterns[0] = '/<a(?![^>]*class)([^>]*)>\s*<img([^>]*)>\s*<\/a>/'; // matches img tag wrapped in anchor tag where anchor tag where anchor has no existing classes
            $replacements[0] = '<a\1 class="' . $classes . '"><img\2><span class="post-content-fb-btn"></span></a>';

            $patterns[1] = '/<a([^>]*)class="([^"]*)"([^>]*)>\s*<img([^>]*)>\s*<\/a>/'; // matches img tag wrapped in anchor tag where anchor has existing classes contained in double quotes
            $replacements[1] = '<a\1class="' . $classes . ' \2"\3><img\4> <span class="post-content-fb-btn"></span></a>';

            $patterns[2] = '/<a([^>]*)class=\'([^\']*)\'([^>]*)>\s*<img([^>]*)>\s*<\/a>/'; // matches img tag wrapped in anchor tag where anchor has existing classes contained in single quotes
            $replacements[2] = '<a\1class="' . $classes . ' \2"\3><img\4> <span class="post-content-fb-btn"></span></a>';

            $html = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $html);

            return $html;
        }

        add_filter('the_content', 'add_classes_to_linked_images', 100, 1);
```

Comment: @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3163506

Answer (score 0):

The following should work with one caveat. The link needs to be on a separate line to the image tag, or the file extension of the image will create a match.

```
/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i
```

Maybe someone can improve on it rather than posting sarcastic comments :)

Comment: This seems to break if the URL doesn't have an extension at all. Do you know how to correct for that?

`<a href="/work/artwork">` should NOT be a match, but still is.